# for loop in selenium doesn't work

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**Code:**

```
try {
  //load file into java
  Workbook workbook=Workbook.getWorkbook(sourceForCustomerGroup);

  //load sheet number (0 is sheet 1)
  Sheet sheetForGroups= workbook.getSheet(0);

  Cell c1 = sheetForGroups.getCell(customerColumn, customerRow);
  String customerGroupName = c1.getContents();

  for (int i = 0; i<sheetForGroups.getRows(); i++, customerRow++) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("tab3")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("new")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("GroupName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("GroupName")).sendKeys(customerGroupName);
    driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();

    customerRow = 1;
    customerColumn = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j<sheetForGroups.getRows()-1; j++, customerRow++) {
      Cell c2 = sheetForGroups.getCell(customerColumn, customerRow);
      String clientUserID = c2.getContents();

      driver.findElement(By.id("clientuserid1")).clear();
      driver.findElement(By.id("clientuserid1")).sendKeys(clientUserID);
      driver.findElement(By.id("add")).click();
    }

    //doesn't work here
    driver.findElement(By.id("actions")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
  }
}
```

The code doesn't seem to run the commands after the second for loop. I have tried tracing it manually and I don't think I've made any logical mistake (I hope I stand corrected). What's wrong?

Comment: Whats the result of your assertTrue ?

Comment: do you see any errors?pls debug and check if you are actually completing both the for loops?

Comment: the loops are completed, yes. it's just the commands after the 2nd for loop that doesn't work.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Can you add your catch block too?

Comment: If the command is executed, but it doesn't work then there is a mistake in the command itself. I have had some problems with sending 'click' events in Selenium myself. Can I assume "actions" and "save" are buttons?